# multiply string in php which is both multiplier and multiplication operator

Tags: php

I got stucked in to achieve 45 from`"0.45*100"` both are in string. How can we get result as 45 from above. i have used eval() function also but no result. Please help.

Comment: WARNING: This is asking for an injection attack. Assuming the `0.45*100` is coming from the user, I would validate it's in the form you expect, extract all the parameters, and then multiply explicitly rather than calling eval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `eval()` which return your operation

```
$test = "0.45*100";
$value=eval("return ($test);");
echo $value;
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/s4XLF)

Comment: thanks. for your simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code using [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

**Working Demo**: https://eval.in/863366

```
$expression = '0.45*100';
eval( '$result = (' . $expression . ');' );
echo $result;
```

Outtput:

```
45
```