# multiply string in js which is both multiplier and multiplication operator

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to transform the example string `"0.45*100"` in a value (`45`).

Another example, if I have two variables `totalCost` and `contractVolume`, and I have the string `"totalCost * 1000 / contractVolume"`: how can I transform the string in the resulting value?
ex.

```
var totalCost = 10
var contractVolume = 100
var stringToCompute = "totalCost * 1000 / contractVolume"
console.log(compute(stringToCompute)) // -> 100
```

Obs:
I see a similar question, but in php, in the example he uses the method eval()

[Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272296/multiply-string-in-php-which-is-both-multiplier-and-multiplication-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use eval() function in javascript

like --

```
eval("x + 17")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) in JS too. Usually it is not a good idea if it is not mandatory, but it works.